# How to set default language to English

Tags: grails, internationalization, locale

I've tried to set it in Bootstrap but it don't work
Also tried in ../conf/spring/resources.groovy .. it don't work either.

In Bootstrap i tried with:

```
Locale defLocale = new Locale("en", "GB");
Locale.setDefault(defLocale);
```

And in resources.groovy I tried this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver
beans = {
    localeResolver(SessionLocaleResolver) { 
        defaultLocale= new java.util.Locale("en","GB") 
  }
}
```

and a lot of variants I found when googling.
I'm sure it must be a way but it seems very hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a session(for example when logging in), you can do the following:

```
if(setDefaultLanguage) {
    session['org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.' +
            'SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'] = 'en-GB'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String springLocaleAtt = 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'
session[springLocaleAtt] = new Locale('en_GB')
```

Comment: I need to have it set before login, the first page should be in english.

Comment: It should work; just place it under your main controller, or something; the one you're using to entertain first page.